# Python Flask Error: While importing 'api', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am bulding a react-flask-project and was trying to run the backend api and getting this error: "Error: While importing 'api', an ImportError was raised.". I tried to run it with yarn and flask but the same error occurs.

**Tree Structure**

```
__ react-flask-project
|
── api
├── api.py
├── .flaskenv
├── config.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── models.py
```

**Routes**

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from app import app
from app.forms import LoginForm

import time

@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    current_time = time.localtime()
    return jsonify({'time': time.strftime('%H:%M', current_time) })

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Ram'}
    return jsonify(user)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
            form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html',  title='Sign In', form=form)
```

**init file**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you import this?
If you just do this `import api`, you need the `__init__.py` in the main Api Folder next to the file api.py. Try `from api import api`